# error when running npm i on client side code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, client

i tried run npm i to project im porking on i got:
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: react-html-parser@2.0.2
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peerOptional react@"^16.9.0 || ^17.0.0 || ^18" from @reduxjs/toolkit@1.9.5
npm ERR!   node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit
npm ERR!     @reduxjs/toolkit@"^1.9.5" from the root project
npm ERR!   17 more (react-async-script, react-dom, react-google-recaptcha, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0-0" from react-html-parser@2.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react-html-parser
npm ERR!   react-html-parser@"^2.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.14.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0-0" from react-html-parser@2.0.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-html-parser
npm ERR!     react-html-parser@"^2.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\User123\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-09-28T11_27_14_227Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User123\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-09-28T11_27_14_227Z-debug-0.log
PS C:\Users\User123\Documents\proj\client> ^C
PS C:\Users\User123\Documents\proj\client> npm i
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: react-html-parser@2.0.2
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peerOptional react@"^16.9.0 || ^17.0.0 || ^18" from @reduxjs/toolkit@1.9.5
npm ERR!   node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit
npm ERR!     @reduxjs/toolkit@"^1.9.5" from the root project
npm ERR!   17 more (react-async-script, react-dom, react-google-recaptcha, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0-0" from react-html-parser@2.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react-html-parser
npm ERR!   react-html-parser@"^2.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.14.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0-0" from react-html-parser@2.0.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-html-parser
npm ERR!     react-html-parser@"^2.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\User123\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-09-28T11_27_40_474Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User123\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-09-28T11_27_40_474Z-debug-0.log

thats the package.json:
{
"name": "client",
"private": true,
"version": "0.0.0",
"type": "module",
"scripts": {
"start": "vite",
"build": "vite build",
"lint": "eslint src --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
"preview": "vite preview"
},
"dependencies": {
"@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
"axios": "^1.4.0",
"chart.js": "^4.3.3",
"dotenv": "^16.3.1",
"quill": "^1.3.6",
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
"react-google-recaptcha": "^3.1.0",
"react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
"react-html-parser": "^2.0.2",
"react-icons": "^4.10.1",
"react-quill": "^2.0.0",
"react-redux": "^8.1.1",
"react-router-dom": "^6.14.1",
"react-toastify": "^9.1.3",
"recharts": "^2.7.2",
"sass": "^1.64.2",
"slate": "^0.94.1",
"slate-react": "^0.98.1",
"socket.io-client": "^4.7.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@types/react": "^18.0.37",
"@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
"@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.0",
"eslint": "^8.38.0",
"eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
"eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
"eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.3.4",
"vite": "^4.3.9"
}
}

any ideas on how to solve this?

i tried to look at the package.json for the relevent parts but i didnt see anything helpful.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score -1):

The error you're encountering is might due to conflicting peer dependencies in your project. Specifically, it seems that the react-html-parser package requires a different version of React than the one specified in your project's dependencies.